# Incluir archivos en librería TypeScript

Tags: typescript, librería

Estoy creando una librería en TypeScript y necesito incluir algunos assets que son necesarios para el funcionamiento de la librería. Concretamente es una librería para trabajar con PDF. El caso es que la librería generará un PDF y le añadirá un botón al final. Este botón lo toma de otro fichero PDF. La librería la "tengo hecha" y funciona todo bien. Pero para generarla y publicarla no veo que añada el fichero PDF del botón. Por diferentes motivos no puedo compartir el código, pero os comparto lo que puedo.

La estructura de archivos del proyecto:

```
dist
 |_index.d.ts
 |_index.js
lib
 |_assets
   |_button.pdf
 |_index.ts
node_modules
.gitignore
package-lock.json
package.json
tsconfig.json
```

package.json:

```json
{
  "name": "libraryName",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "dist/index.js",
  "types" : "dist/index.d.ts",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tsc"
  },
  "author": "buclefor",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^14.14.32",
    "typescript": "^4.2.3"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    ...
  }
}
```

Los import's de la librería (lib/index.ts):

```js
import ...
import axios from 'axios';
const button = require('./assets/button.pdf');
```

Lo que necesito es que la librería al instalarla incluya todo lo que necesita para funcionar.

**Solucion:**

Al final he conseguido solucionarlo, he usado

```js
const button = require('./assets/button.pdf');
```

para incluir el botón, eso es posible gracias a file-loader de webpack, os dejo un [link](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/file-loader/)

Luego en el package.json hay que poner lo siguiente:

```json
  "files": [
    "dist/*",
    "assets/*"
  ],
```

de esta forma, al publicar se incluyen los archivos que necesito.

Comment: Y en la librería que "tienes hecha" cómo incluyes el PDF del botón?

Comment: Con esta línea:

const button= require('./assets/button.pdf');

Luego uso la variable donde la necesito.

Comment: Entonces cuando dices que la tienes hecha eso no incluye el botón?

Comment: A ver, la librería está hecha e incluye al botón. Cuando digo que "está hecha", con las comillas, es porque está escrita pero no veo que me la genere con los archivos que necesita. Por otro lado, el código lo escribí dentro de otro proyecto donde funciona perfectamente, pero ahora la estoy sacando como librería para poder reutilizarla.

Comment: Si en el otro proyecto funciona debieras poder extraerla encapsulando todos los componentes, incluyendo el botón. En la versión que funciona no creo que uses require en un PDF porque no es algo que puedas requerir. Es un binario que tendrías que obtener con fs.readFile

Comment: Pues así lo tengo hecho y funciona perfectamente mediante file-loader. He estado viendo que mediante el atributo "files" se puede indicar que es lo que se publica. Pero no tengo claro que al instalar la librería desde NPM (que lo haré de forma privada usando Verdaccio) también se instalen los ficheros que le indique ahí.

Comment: Mira la librería [copyfiles](https://www.npmjs.com/package/copyfiles). Modifica el script `build` para que quede algo como `tsc && copyfiles u -1 lib/assets/*.pdf build`. Entonces lo que ocurrirá es que primero se compila y se crea el directorio *build* y al finalizar copia los archivos de la carpeta *assets* dentro de *build/assets*. No estoy seguro si el argumento `u -1` sea necesario, pero con una revisada a la documentación y un par de pruebas debería ser suficiente. No creo que sea necesario escribir una respuesta, pero de ser necesario con gusto elaboro mejor el ejemplo. Saludos.

Comment: Bueno, os cuento, he estado probando con fs.readFile, pero no me sirve. Por lo que he estado leyendo solo sirve para el backend. Lo que estoy haciendo es una librería para el frontend. Necesito leer un fichero PDF que va incluida en la propia librería, si no puedo usar file-loader y no puedo usar fs.readFile no se que otras opciones me quedan.
Respecto a lo de copyfiles, al final lo hice con el atribute "files" en package.json y funcionó bien.